# html table background image is not working

Tags: php, html-table

I am trying to display background image for table but it is not working for whole table. Here is code:

```
echo"
        <font color='white'>
        <table  width=620 height=600 border='1' style='background-image:url(good.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat;' >  
        <col width=40%>
  <col width=60%>

        <tr bgcolor='#0B0B61' >
        <th > &nbsp; Results for <strong>Tracking Number:</strong>    </th>
        <th>&nbsp; ". $tid . "</th> 

         </tr>

        <tr bgcolor='#0B0B61' >
        <td><strong> &nbsp; Status:</strong> </td>
        <td>&nbsp;". $status .  "</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

It works if I set it  for table row or td.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set background color for each row, which overrides the table background.

And I must say your code looks like you wrote it 15 years ago.
You should use `class` instead of inline styling such as `bgcolor` , `<strong>`, `width`, `border`

For example:

```css
.your-table {
  color: white;
  width: 620px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-image: url('https://gallery-wallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/beach-scene-wallpaper-for-desktop-desktop-wallpaper-beach-scenes.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.first-col{
  width: 40%;
}

.second-col{
  width: 60%;
}

.tracking-number, .status{
  font-weight: bold;
}

td{
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<table class='your-table'>
  <col class='first-col'>
  <col class='second-col'>
  <tr>
    <th>Results for <span="tracking-number">Tracking Number:</span> </th>
    <th>". $tid . "</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='status'>Status:</td>
    <td>". $status . "</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: if i set it for every row , it look like every row have starting point of image . i am not getting background image at all

Comment: You need to remove the background from your rows

Answer (score 0):

```css
.table-bg {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/unified/sprites.svg?v=e5e58ae7df45");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<table class='table-bg'>
  <col width=100%>

  <tr>
    <td><strong> &nbsp; Status:</strong> </td>
    <td>&nbsp;". $status . "</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```